# Who gets what and why does a player making three others fold get nothing

Tags: texas-hold-em

Game is Texas Hold'em

Situation:

Blinds 3000 and 5000 with first three players calling 5000. Fourth person, the small blind, goes all in at 6000 the following player being big blind goes all in at 36000. The first three that had bet the 5000 all fold.

Questions:

What does the player that bet all in at 36000 get for making the 3 players fold? What can the player that only bet 6000 play for?

Seems to me the player that made the three players fold with the 36000 bet should get something. The game I played said she wins nothing and the 15000 plus 6000 from each remaining players all go in the same pot, and both remaining players get a shot at all the money and the 36000 bet gets zero.

Comment: Mr. BigStack knows the rules before he bets, and he therefore knows that if he causes everyone to fold except the all-in player, he has to beat that player in order to win any money. That should affect his decision to raise; a pure bluff would be a terrible play here (in fact, an unethical play because it's sure to help the all-in player more than himself).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I would disagree that its necessarily unethical. MBS is realising his equity heads up while only contributing ~25% of the pot. This is +EV for him even with bluffs. If its a tournament, then it may depend on payout structure.

Comment: It's unethical if it's a pure bluff--i.e., his equity is zero.

Answer (score 2):

"What does the player that bet all in at 36000 get for making the 3 players fold?"

She gets them to fold.

"What can the player that only bet 6000 play for?"

He/she can play to a maximum of 6000 per opponent.

"The game I played said she wins nothing and the 15000 plus 6000 from each remaining players all go in the same pot, and both remaining players get a shot at all the money and the 36000 bet gets zero"

She doesnt win nothing, and she doesn't get zero. She wins the option to realise her equity in the pot heads up and increase her chance of winning the hand, which is much more than if it were 4-way. The nature of poker is that when opponents fold to your bet, they are giving up their equity in the hand. You can't win more than whats in the pot, whether you think you deserve it or not.

In this specific scenario, one other player is already all in and can no longer fold. That doesn't mean the player who bets does not benefit, though it does mean the all-in player benefits the most.